# how to add unchanged column with recalculated columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe. I want to keep the first two columns unchanged but change the rest of the columns as follows:

```
df1[3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)]))
```

I dont know how to add the changed columns to the unchanged columns to provide a new dataset.

```
Original set

chr    leftPos     Sample
1        234234       3221
2         12324       4322
2         143413     13243


Output
chr    leftPos     Sample
1        234234     7x10-4
2         12324     3x10-4
2         143413    2x10-3
```

etc.

I tried

```
 dftry <- as.data.frame(df1[2:3],df1[3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)]))
```

but I got

```
Error in     as.data.frame.data.frame(df1[2:3],df1[3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])) : 
  invalid 'row.names', length 37 for a data frame with 22849 rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df1[3:ncol(df1)] <-
    df1[3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])[col(df1[3:ncol(df1)])]
```

You could use `data.frame` instead of `as.data.frame` and the error will not be there, but if I understand correctly, each column `df1[3:ncol(df1)]` should be divided by the corresponding `colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])`.  In your code, it divides the first row of say 3rd column by 1st `colSums`, then 2nd row by 2nd colSums etc.. We could avoid that by  `replicating` the elements of `colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])`, each by the length of `3:ncol(df1)` or use `col(df1[3:ncol(df1)])`

In your example data showed, there is only one column i.e. `3rd`, so it wouldn't matter to use  `colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])[col(df1[3:ncol(df1)])]`, i.e . there is only a single `colSums`.

But, suppose your dataset is

```
  set.seed(24)
  df1 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:30, 20*5, replace=TRUE),
     ncol=5))

  head(df1[3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])[col(df1[3:ncol(df1)])],3)
  #         V3         V4         V5
  #1 0.05932203 0.05084746 0.05776173
  #2 0.04661017 0.02372881 0.01083032
  #3 0.03389831 0.02711864 0.05415162
 head(df1[3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)]),3)
 #        V3         V4         V5
 #1 0.05932203 0.05415162 0.05423729
 #2 0.03728814 0.02966102 0.01083032
 #3 0.02888087 0.02711864 0.06355932
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe already done but have you tried?

```
cbind(df1[,2:3], df1[,3:ncol(df1)]/colSums(df1[3:ncol(df1)])))
```

By the way, you said two were unchanged, so it shouldn't be?

```
df1[,1:2]
```